# Discord.js Bot responds to message or command during specific time only

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can I apply check Date to this message so that the discord.js bot does not respond to *"nio down*" if it's a **weekday** between **9:30am and 4:00pm Eastern** time zone? (Stock Market hours)

Please excuse my code. I'm a complete noob and trying to learn through the expierence and execution of it. I tend to learn better through examples than trying to study and read through books. Once I have a better grasp on it all then I like to narrow it down and read through the books to fine tune or correct some of my bad habits if that makes sense.

```
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("nio down")) {
    message.channel.startTyping();
    setTimeout(() => message.channel.send("y’all got duped. nio CEO on the run now"), 56500);
    setTimeout(() => message.channel.send("pookie made more money hustling"), 69500);
    message.channel.stopTyping(true);
  } else
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. Access the `createdTimestamp` property of the message use the `getDay()` method to check whether it is a weekday:

```
const { createdTimestamp } = message;
const date = new Date(createdTimestamp);
const day = date.getDay();

// The getDay() method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday
if (day > 0 && day < 6) {
  console.log("weekday");
  const UTCHours = date.getUTCHours();
  const ESTHours = UTCHours - 5.0;

  if (ESTHours == 9) {
    const minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();

    if (minutes < 30) {
      console.log("Not in time", ESTHours, minutes);
    }
  } else if (ESTHours > 10 || ESTHours < 16) {
    console.log("In time", ESTHours);
  } else {
    console.log("Not in time", ESTHours);
  }
} else {
  console.log("No weekday");
}
```

The eastern time zone check is more complicated. Native Date objects only know two timezones, UTC and the user's locale timezone (but the amount of information you can extract about the locale timezone is limited). You could work in UTC and subtract / add the necessary amount of hours from the message object.

Or you look into one of the date libraries like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) or [Day.js](https://day.js.org/) which are better suited to handle that kind of problem.

**EDIT**

You can get the UTC hours via the [getUTCHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours) method. Then subtract the time difference and check whether the time falls within the boundaries of *9:30* - *16:00*.

Comment: I don't mind the UTC time zone how would I add this to the above?